# Show "save dialog" on top of the "main program" in C# when clicked on taskbar in Windows

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

Problem: When a simulation is complete a "save dialog" pops up. When clicked on the "main program" in the Windows taskbar, both the "main program" and the "save dialog" should come on top of other open windows. Right now just the "main program" is showing while the "save dialog is hidden in the background and all windows has to be minimized to see it. How to solve this?

Comment: A bit difficult to answer without seeing your code, but are you showing your SaveDialog with `saveDialog.ShowDialog()`? e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx

Comment: Yes, I am. The "save dialog" is working and is showing when it should. No problem there. The problem is that if the "main program" is minimized and when it is maximized again both the "main program" and "save dialog" should be on top of the screen. So I need a connection between the "main program" and "save dialog". When I click on the program in the taskbar all windows belonging to that one should be on top, not just the main program. Did that help?

Comment: Fair enough, without seeing your code I can't really offer much help, but sounds like you may want to make use of the Form.Activated event on the main form (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated.aspx) and use this to show the save dialog.

Answer (score 0):

call ShowDialog method to make you saveFileDialog as a modal dialog box

```
saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```